# External Table is not in the Expected format. C# Xls file

Tags: c#, datatable, xls

We tried to get the XLS file data into Data table in C#. We got error on the line `con.Open();`  using the below connection string ,

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName  + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'"
```

The Error is:

> External Table is not in the Expected format.

We tried with almost all the different connection strings. 
But not able to find a solution.
If any solution available , kindly let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure its an xls file and not just a file with a .xls extension?

Comment: Yes, its a complete xls file.

Comment: Well if you are sure thats the case, then I dont know.. normally I would have said its a csv file with .xls extension